# save and view data in core coming int date text field

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm having problems when displaying the field "number" in the case is of type int but actually do not know if I could record "number" with success because I can not view the recorded data within core data.Por then it will show the two steps, which I saved and that we display the value "number"

```
let myIntNumber : NSNumber = (Int(numero.text!) as? NSNumber)!
 user.setValue(myIntNumber , forKey: "numero")
//This is the code to save

 Int(numero.text!) = user.valueForKey("numero") as? NSNumber
//That's the code to display
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to set/retrieve an `Int` value into dictionary?

Comment: no, I'm trying to save and view at a given core data coming from the Int type text field

Comment: Is your `user` property `NSDictionary` type?

Comment: do not use anything NSDictionary type just want to transform the string data type int coming from a text field and save and display of a core data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fetch the `text` property from `UITextField` it is always a `String` data type. You will have to validate whether the value entered is numeric and you can store it accordingly. In order to validate and store it,

```
//Setting value to user property
if let textFieldValue = numero.text {
    if !textFieldValue.isEmpty && (Double(textFieldValue) != nil) { // If success, value in TextField is Numeric
        let number = NSNumber(integer: Int(textFieldValue)!) // For Int type.
        user.setValue(number, forKey: "numero")
    }
}
```

To set your integer value from core data to `numero`,

```
//Fetching value from user property
if let number = user.valueForKey("numero") as? String {
    if !number.isEmpty && (Double(number) != nil) { // If success, number to set in TextField is Numeric
        numero.text = number
    }
}
```

*Note: I have not handled any error condition. You will have to ensure all error scenarios are handled appropriately.*

Comment: hi i ran the code and at compile time gave an error that is this: reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "number"; Desired type = NSNumber; Given type = __NSCFString; value = 45324263643. 'in core data I put the data type as integer 16 but I have to leave as String?

Comment: Is your `number` property's data type Int16? or Int? Can you post the ManagedObject model code in your question? It will be easier to debug with that information.

Comment: I have updated the code to take NSNumber type. Glad it worked for you! If the solution helped resolving the issue, you could mark it as answered.

Comment: what I'm looking kkkk is the first time I make a question where my March issue like answered?

Comment: You will have to click the check mark next to the answer. If you need more info refer [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) link